# how to get "(8am - 5pm)" from the given string "Delivery Time (8am - 5pm)" in a best possible way in javascript?

Tags: jquery

How to get

```
(8am - 5pm)
```

from the given string

```
Delivery Time (8am - 5pm)
```

in a best possible way in JavaScript?

Comment: `'Delivery Time (8am - 5pm)'.replace('Delivery Time ', '');` ?

Comment: As the prefix text changes all the time like Delivery time or standard delivery or delivering today.

Comment: That's hard to evaluate with a sample size of 1... Can you please edit the question and provide more examples, together with your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"your string with the words and range (8am - 6pm)".replace(/.*\(/, "(")
```

Should replace everything up to the last (.